# What are hard/flat buttons (on appliances) called?

Tags: phrase-requests

What are the kind of push buttons used on modern appliances called:

- Lies flush with the surface.
- Have to press (not tap) to activate.
- Button usually doesn't move much or at all when you press it.
- Usually seamless or a slight seam with the surface.
- Often the same material over the whole surface, including buttons.
- Often seen on surfaces that need to be cleaned frequently or water/splash proof... Stove, washer/dryer, point of sale terminals, and most recently a new printer.

Originally I was writing a review and wanted to complain that the _____ type of buttons were hard to use, not like normal buttons. But now I just want to know since it seems like these are showing up everywhere.

Comment: I suggest you try this on [engineering.se].

Comment: Probably **control panel**: https://www.amazon.com/Whirlpool-W10211459-Control-Panel-Microwave/dp/B005B44FGK/ref=asc_df_B005B44FGK/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=167167561169&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16807483781586274479&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9012344&hvtargid=pla-309552163336&psc=1

Comment: @Bread , no, OP wants the specific type, ie [dimple](https://www.technobuffalo.com/2016/12/01/this-dimple-4-button-nfc-sticker-offers-convenient-one-tap-access-to-your-favorite-smartphone-features/) panel, [tactile control assembly](https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/spec/WD21X10504), etc. There are quite a number of terms for them.

Comment: @Phil Sweet ~ we ordinary consumers just call them control panels, and leave it at that.

Comment: @Bread and you probably call a repairman in to fix them, because he knows what to call the broken part, and therefore can order a new one. This is why I suggested Engineering.SE.

Comment: @Phil Sweet ~ True, but the repairmen always seem to know what I mean by *button* or *control panel*.

Comment: @Bread but typing in "control panel" in a search engine when looking for parts, either for a DIY project or to repair an appliance yourself, will bring too many results to filter through.

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey not if you include the product model number in the search, which is exactly what the repair guys do.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Membrane switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_switch), where one contact of the switch assembly is embedded in a flexible substrate.

Comment: Technically, your normal (desktop or laptop) keyboard is very likely also of membrane type internally, but for the OP's phrase it's probably the best word.

Comment: 'Membrane panel' would describes the panel, rather than the switch mechanism. You can have mechanical switches behind a membrane panel (most often seen on heavy industrial equipment), or membrane switches behind separate button caps (e.g. a calculator keyboard with hard plastic buttons will probably be a tactile membrane switch).

Comment: This would be a better answer if you quoted relevant parts of the Wikipedia entry you linked to, and maybe include an illustration or two.  Also, you should *say* that you’re citing Wikipedia.

Answer (score 14):

[**Touch pad**](https://www.fix.com/repair/appliance/microwave/touchpad-does-not-respond/):

> If the touch pads on your microwave oven do not respond but the display lights up, the problem is most likely with the membrane switch. This component, which is more commonly referred to as the touch pad, is actually a series of soft touch electrical switches.

I had originally thought of this as a "touch panel" and Googled [that](https://www.google.com/search?q=microwave%20touch%20panel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) (along with "microwave"). But I then noticed that many of the repair sites referred to it as a "touch pad" (or "touchpad," without the space) instead.

Here, also, is what [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch%20pad) says about *touch pad*:

> a keypad for an electronic device (such as a microwave oven) that consists of a flat surface divided into several differently marked areas which are touched to choose options

Comment: Ever since capacitive touch went mainstream in 2007, I've felt like the word "touch" on a user interface implies there is no need to *press*, and therefore a "touch pad" is distinctly different from a membrane switch/pad/keyboard because you do have to press on a membrane to activate it, but a touch interface can merely be touched.

Comment: One of the OP's conditions was that one has to press (not tap) the 'buttons' to activate them. Wouldn't the term *touch pad* include the displays with virtual buttons that one merely taps?

Comment: Whether you "tap" or "press," your finger still has to contact the surface in some way. So, while "touch" may be too general a term, it's the term that was coined. (Nobody came up with "press pad" versus "tap pad.")

Answer (score 7):

“Touch-sensitive buttons” as sold here: https://gblockingsystems.co.uk/locking-systems/touch-sensitive-buttons/

> GB Locking Systems range of high quality touch sensitive exit / entry buttons. An ideal replacement for conventional push buttons, door release buttons, call switches, etc. Ideal for the elderly and disabled – no pressure required operates with the lightest of touches.

If it’s a switch then it’s a “touch switch”:

> A touch switch is a type of switch that only has to be touched by an object to operate. It is used in many lamps and wall switches that have a metal exterior as well as on public computer terminals.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_switch

Comment: But do touch switches fulfil the "press, not tap" requirement?

Answer (score 6):

They are called buttons.  I am not being facetious.

Comment: This doesn't help if you are trying to buy a replacement for your microwave or diswasher.

Comment: @Phil Sweet ~ the question didn't mention anything about buying parts. Personally, I call them either one: *buttons* (a throwback term which I still use out of a sense of nostalgia) -- or when feeling more modern: *control panels*. "Let's see now, I need to go over to the *control panel* on my machine and *hit* the on *button*."

Comment: @PhilSweet, you don't really buy a replacement "button," mostly because they're not a single component from an electronics perspective. It's still the correct term of art for the aggregate. This particular kind of button is a non-tactile button (which I put in an answer as well), but it's a button all the same!

Comment: A control panel might contain several buttons. A single button is not a control panel.

Answer (score 6):

That's a "non-tactile button", illustrated below.

[image: Tactile vs non-tactile button]

Answer (score -3):

They are known as "haptic" buttons

> *The buttons are actually pressable, while haptic feedback completes the experience.*

[haptic - definition and synonyms](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/haptic)

Comment: No. 'Haptic' devices relay sensory feedback (like a vibration) to the person operating them.